# SignalR Scale out with Azure Service Bus Topic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, signalr, servicebus

I started learning SignalR. And having some requirement to implement SignalR with Service Bus backplane.

I just try to create very simple demo.

Where there is one API application running on azure connected with service bus topic using signalr.

And there is multiple instance of MVC application is open which is also hosted on Azure.

I want to broadcast message using signalr to all receivers.

I checked many documents. Following are the links.

[SignalR Scaleout with Azure Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-windows-azure-service-bus)

Also tried to create simple console application in which one aaplication will send message to service bus and all other console application will able to receive that message.

Is this architechture complex?

Can anybody provide simple demo and clear understading of how Hub is supposed to work?

And how i can implement this functionality?

Comment: In the configuration page of your webApp, check the WebSockets setting, select On.
WebSockets setting: On

Comment: start to use signlr, if that works, add servicebus. you don't need to start with servicebus and signlr

Comment: Just as some extra info, Azure now has this service: [Azure SignalR Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/signalr-service/)